# Getting ruby 1.8 error in my 1.9.3 ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I tired to run a migration and I got this error.

```
/home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-linux]
```

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and nokogiri 1.5.2 but why is there ruby 1.8.7 in the error.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what caused the error? It is very odd indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out. The path to ruby was not set properly. I did `rvm use 1.9.3` and everything went fine.